# Wordpress http to https home redirect (ERR TOO MANY REDIRECTS)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

So, I moved my wordpress blog to https, and it works, all inner pages work perfectly. If I access the https home version it works perfectly, but if I access the http version it doesnt redirect to the https version.
To clarify:
If I access http://example.com/article it redirects to https://example.com/article which is perfect
But if I access http://example.com it doesnt redirect.

I tried adding many codes posted in other answers here in stackoverflow, but I always end up getting the ERR TOO MANY REDIRECTS error, any idea how to fix this? I spent the last 2 days on this and starting to feel a bit stupid.

My current htaccess is:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    #The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css   application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom_xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php application/x-httpd-fastphp text/html

    #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
        Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>


# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

URL is correctly set to https in settings

Comment: pls update your question with `.htaccess` code, and have you set home URL and site URL with `https` version?

Comment: Without the specific rules, nobody can help you. Please show the .htaccess.

Comment: updated with htaccess and yes, it is set to https in settings

Comment: There is no rule anywhere in this .htaccess to redirect to https.

Comment: @OlafDietsche If I add the following I get the ERR TOO MANY REDIRECTS error:
  
`RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]`